# ForEach runs only for specific times on update

Tags: swiftui

I have a view defined below. On buttons click , `Go Back` and `save & continue` , I update the `currentIndex`.

My LeftView ForEach exhibiting a strange behavior. It calls the for loop only limited number of times. Ideally it should call the `let _ = print(index)` 5 times. However it calls it 5 times only on initial render and afterwards, if I change the value of `currentIndex`, the loop is called twice for different indexes each time. The log for

```
let _ = print("\(title) \(self.isActive)") inside BulletView is
```

Initially ->

```
Customer Information true
System Information false
Payment false
Add Template false
Receipt false
```

One 1x increment when currentIndex is 1

```
Customer Information true
System Information false
```

One 2nd increment when currentIndex is 2

```
System Information false
Payment false
```

Why is it exhibiting this behavior and why other `BulletViews` are not updated.

```
fileprivate let titlesList = ["Customer Information",
                              "System Information",
                              "Payment",
                              "Add Template",
                              "Receipt"]

struct InstallationView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = InstallationViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { metrics in
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    LeftView(currentIndex: $viewModel.currentIndex)
                        .frame(width: metrics.size.width * 0.35)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    RightView(currentIndex: $viewModel.currentIndex)
                        .frame(width: metrics.size.width * 0.65)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true).navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

fileprivate struct LeftView: View {
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int
     
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<titlesList.count, id: \.self) { index in
                let _ = print(index)
                BulletView(count: index + 1,
                           title: titlesList[index],
                           isActive: (currentIndex == index),
                           showTopSeparator: (index != 0),
                           showBottomSeparator: (index != titlesList.count - 1))
            }
        }.padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 100, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
    }
}

fileprivate struct RightView: View {
    
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int

    private let edges = EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 20, trailing: 20)
    private let leftEdges = EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(titlesList[currentIndex])
                    .font(Font(UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                
                containedView()
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: { currentIndex -= 1 }) {
                        Text("Go Back")
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 70)
                            .font(Font(UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color(Constants.Colors.main))
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: { currentIndex += 1 }) {
                        Text("Save & Continue")
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 70)
                            .font(Font(UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color(Constants.Colors.main))
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                    }
                }
                .padding(edges)
            }.padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 80, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
    
    func containedView() -> AnyView {
        switch currentIndex {
        case 0:
            return AnyView(CustomerView())
        case 1:
            return AnyView(SystemView())
        case 2:
            return AnyView(PaymentView())
        default:
            return AnyView(CustomerView())
        }
    }
}

struct InstallationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        InstallationView().previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid to use an index for `ForEach` as the identifier. The identifier is required to be stable for a given entity.

So this line is wrong:

```
        ForEach(0..<titlesList.count, id: \.self) { index in
```

If you do not change the number of elements, then SwiftUI will assume that there are no changes (id 0 is first, id 1 is second, etc).

Instead, this should be:

```
        ForEach(titlesList) { title in
```

And the element of `titleList` should be an `Identifiable` struct.

That said, `let _ = print(index)` is meaningless in a SwiftUI View. SwiftUI views are not executable code. They **describe** the View. They do not **create** the View. `body` can be evaluated many times (that's why it's a property, not a function), or it may be cached or copied. You should not expect it being evaluated to have any relationship to the View being refreshed.